# How many concurrent HTTP connections from a single tab do modern browsers support?

Tags: http, browsers, browser-support

I'm trying to figure out how many concurrent HTTP connections from a single tab modern browsers support.

I've found [old sources saying 10 for Chrome and 17 for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

I'm confused by this because my default `network.http.max-connections` in Firefox is set to `900`:

[image]

In Chrome, I can't find a similar setting anywhere.

How many concurrent HTTP connections can I have from a single tab for Firefox/Chrome/Safari?

**NB**: I'm concerned about both the maximum number of connections *to the same domain* **and** the maximum number of connections *all domains included*.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a tool like Fiddler to see how many connections your browser is opening per tab? The tool is available here:

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

It will allow you to debug your whole socket and see what is going on. Good luck!

Comment: because it is not free and not opensource